# Why does gcc warn about incompatible struct assignment with a `self = [super initDesignatedInit];' call in derived class?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, warnings

I have the following base/derived class setup in Objective-C:

```
@interface ASCIICodeBase : NSObject {
 @protected
  char code_[4];
}
- (Base *)initWithASCIICode:(const char *)code;
@end

@implementation ASCIICodeBase
- (ASCIICodeBase *)initWithCode:(const char *)code len:(size_t)len {
  if (len == 0 || len > 3) {
    return nil;
  }
  if (self = [super init]) {
    memset(code_, 0, 4);
    strncpy(code_, code, 3);
  }
  return self;
}
@end

@interface CountryCode : ASCIICodeBase
- (CountryCode *)initWithCode:(const char *)code;
@end
@implementation CountryCode
- (CountryCode *)initWithCode:(const char *)code {
  size_t len = strlen(code);
  if (len != 2) {
    return nil;
  }
  self = [super initWithCode:code len:len]; // here
  return self;
}
@end
```

On the line marked "here", I get the following gcc warning:

`warning: incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct ASCIICodeBase *', expected 'struct CurrencyCode *'`

Is there something wrong with this code or should I have the `ASCIICodeBase` return `id`? Or maybe use a cast on the "here" line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `(id)` as the return value type.

Objective-C doesn't support covariant declarations.  Consider:

```
@interface NSArray:NSObject
+ (id) array;
@end
```

Now, you can call `+array` on both `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.  The former returns an immutable array and the latter a mutable array.   Because of Objective-C's lack of covariant declaration support, if the above were declared as returning `(NSArray*)`, clients of the subclasses method would have to cast to `(NSMutableArray*).   Ugly, fragile, and error prone.   Thus, using the generic type is, generally, the most straightforward solution.

So... if you are declaring a method that returns an instance of a specific class, typecast explicitly.  If you are declaring a method that will be overridden and that override may return a subclass *and* the fact that it returns a subclass will be exposed to clients, then use `(id)`.

Designated initializers work the same way.  An `-init*` method may return an instance of just about any type, depending on context of implementation (of course).   Thus, the return type of initialization methods is covariant and, as a result, you need to use `(id)` as the return type.

No need to file a bug -- there are several already.

---

Note that LLVM now has an `instancetype` keyword that can be used in place of `id` in a declaration like the above.  It means "this method returns an instance that passes an `isKindOfClass:` test of the class upon which it was called", effectively.

Comment: I was expecting the covariant return type support I'm used to in C++. (id) for such base class messages it is.

Comment: Why shouldn't these “autorelease-constructors” and friends use `instancetype` instead of `id`?

Comment: BTW, it seems that clang supports covariant return types for Objective C now.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-PhilippePellet -- that is correct.  When I wrote the above, it did not.

Answer (score 4):

You should cast the return value to (CountryCode *). The method returns a value of type `ASCIICodeBase *`, which is less specific than `CountryCode *`

So:

```
self = (CountryCode *) [super initWithCode:code len:len];
```

But what you should really do is set the return type to `(id)`. That's how it's usually done in Objective-C.

Comment: I have no idea. When you're participating on StackOverflow, I guess you have to get used to these coward-downvotes.

Comment: Yeah, why would this get downvoted? It's the reason the warning is appearing. People are strange.

Comment: Today, with clang, you should probably use the `instancetype` return type instead of `id` (though [clang automatically replaces `id` with `instancetype` but the `init` method family](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-features), but not for all other constructor-like methods).