# Why does NSArray arrayWithObjects and friends return id and not NSArray*?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Basic Cocoa newbie question here… This seems to be a very common pattern in Cocoa. Why do init methods and autoreleased object creation methods like `[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ...]` return `id`? Why is returning `NSArray *` (or the actual type being created) not in every way better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another reason is typed selector matching of the return value. If `[NSArray arrayWithObjects: ...]` returned an `NSArray` (by declaration), then `NSMutableArray` would need to re-declare `arrayWithObjects:` with a different return type (otherwise you would get a warning when writing `NSMutableArray * a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]`).

Even if you went that route, message chaining can quickly lead to ambiguities when the compiler tries to match selectors to types/non-types. So... selector's return and parameter types should match in this scenario. Consequently, the return type `id` is used.

If you have tried to build a strictly typed objc hierarchy with such constructors and use a high warning level, you will see how this ambiguity unfolds. Of course, the NSArray/NSMutableArray example is sufficient to describe the problem.

Comment: Java and C++ allow overridden methods to have covariant return types. Objective has no such thing, then?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet it's not a good idea to use that written style, especially if you are dealing with non-objc objects. all the dynamism you need exists, but the compiler has a difficult time matching types/selectors/return types. an objc selector does not define return types or parameter types (although they can be queried of specific implementations), and dispatch is always dynamic so. because dispatch is dynamic, you should also favor selectors' parameter and return types to match. it does work well in practice. `[NSMutableArray array]` obviously returns an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet (cont) despite (source level) type erasure though `id`. and trojanfoe linked a very good explanation by bbum. of course, you are free to try it, but initializers and constructors are generally one-liners so you immediately (re)introduce the type using your variable declaration.

Comment: But I can reintroduce a wrong type without the compiler even issuing a warning. Isn't it very disturbing that I can perfectly well write `NSMutableArray *a1 = [NSArray array]; [a1 addObject:@"wrong!"];` with no error?

Comment: Followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248437/in-objective-c-why-am-i-allowed-to-assign-an-nsarray-to-an-nsmutablearray-witho

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet re disturbing: fwiw... the language's type safety has improved a lot in recent years; notably, since clang. the idioms/conventions have also improved. of course, you can introduce your own type safety to reduce the possibility of such issues. but to answer your question: "Yes", although static checking is only part of the equation :) i introduce static and dynamic checking.

Answer (score 2):

`init` methods return `id` so they can return the same class as its superclass.

Objective-C collection classes return `id` as they can store any type of Objective-C object.

Comment: See my comment on Justin's answer regarding covariant return types

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet No Objective-C doesn't support covariant return types.  See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433504/why-does-gcc-warn-about-incompatible-struct-assignment-with-a-self-super-ini

Comment: OK, so my followup question is: why shouldn't it return `instancetype` instead of `id`?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet `instancetype` is an extension introduced by clang (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objc_instancetype) and the libraries existed before clang did, so I guess `id` is used mainly for historical purposes.

Comment: Also, clang seems to have no problem with covariant return types, even if I don't use `instanceof`. Thus, `+(NSArray *)array;` in `NSArray` and `+(NSMutableArray *)array` in `NSMutableArray` would compile fine and be usable as expected, it seems.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Agreed; it's fine to return the actual type in such *constructor methods*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25695/discussion-between-jean-philippe-pellet-and-trojanfoe)

Answer (score 0):

Acutally it DOES return an NSArray/NSMutalbeArray/whatever.

It is just that id is the generic return value of init. So the return value is declared as id but it is an NSArray that is being returned.

But frankly, I cannot give you any good answer to your "why" question. When ever I overwrite init methods in a subclass I let them have return ABC* if the class' name is ABC. And it just works fine.

Comment: Seems like there's no problem with `init` and some other special methods because [clang treats them specially and automatically inserts the `instancetype` return type](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objc_instancetype).

Comment: Which means by explicitely stating the class that I am implementing I do not cause a problem directly but may cause difficulties if the class that I am currently developing is being subclassed later.