# In Objective C, why am I allowed to assign an NSArray to an NSMutableArray without error or warning?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, clang

I'm disturbed by a weird behavior, illustrated by the following example:

```
NSMutableArray *a1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // fine
NSMutableArray *a2 = [NSMutableArray array];        // fine, too

// compiler reports incompatible pointer types; good:
NSMutableArray *a3 = [[NSArray alloc] init]; 

// compiler says nothing and is happy to assign this!
NSMutableArray *a4 = [NSArray array];
```

Both `init` and `array` method of both the `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` classes return `id`. However, the behavior when I call these methods is simply not the same, and clang lets me happily assign an empty `NSArray` to an `NSMutableArray` variable!

It turns out that [clang will automatically change the return type of some methods, including the `init` family, to `instancetype`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objc_instancetype), and thus be able to determine at compile time that `[[NSArray alloc] init]` returns an `NSArray *` and not an `NSMutableArray *`. But this check simply doesn't work with the `array` method.

Why? Shouldn't lines like my last example generate *at least* a warning? Why aren't all these methods declared as returning `instancetype`? Will it change in the future?

---

**Update**

Good news: as of iOS 7, `[NSArray array]` returns `instancetype`, so the assignment to `a4` above also yields a warning. Other methods like `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` or `arrayWithContentsOfURL` still return `id`, though…

Comment: I would file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com and mention the bug number here.

Comment: @ericgorr problem is, it's not a bug.

Comment: If you do like this, it again accepts, without any warning... id mem=[NSArray alloc];
    NSMutableArray *s3=[mem init];
    NSLog(@"%@",s3);

Comment: @CodaFi Can't it be considered a bug that the convenience constructors like `array` don't return `instancetype`?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: if it is bug as not returning instanceType then what about `[mem init]` as in my example.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Your example is fine. You're using `id` as a type, and made the conscious decision to opt out of type safety. You're on your own, you can't blame the compiler. My problem is: I want type safety, and I can get it only if the method name begins with `init` and not for a convenience constructor like `array`. Bummer.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: I disagree with my decision of choosing id. Its not my decision. I checked and found alloc returns id, so i used id.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet : And sorry as I copied your question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249505/incompatible-pointer-types-initializing-subclass-strong-with-an-expression/15249658?noredirect=1#comment21505308_15249658

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I think you're misunderstanding what `id` is used for.

Comment: @CodaFi It seems clear it is not the expected or desired behavior. Such things are worth reporting to Apple whether you want to consider them real bugs or not.

Comment: Bug report rdar://13357852

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15250830/468724

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But this check simply doesn't work with the array method. Why?

As the document you have linked describes, it is because `-array` does not yield a recognized *Related Result Type*. ObjC is very dynamic -- the compiler cannot guarantee the result type of `+array`. It does make that assumption with some methods because the naming conventions are well defined (e.g. `+alloc`, `-init`, `+new`, `-self`, etc.). So this implementation simply resorts to naming conventions.

The compiler also validates some naming conventions in areas you may not expect:

```
@implementation NSArray (DEMO)

- (id)initStr
{
    return [NSString new]; // << warning. RE: init prefix
}

@end
```

> Shouldn't lines like my last example generate at least a warning? Why aren't all these methods declared as returning instancetype? Will it change in the future?

`instancetype` was introduced about one year ago (from the looks of it). Some of the APIs were written decades ago. I suspect it will happen -- *in time* -- because (if used correctly) it can point out a lot of issues in existing code. Of course, those changes would break existing builds (again, typically good corrections if declared in the right places).

So file bugs and give the tools and libraries a few years to update. Assuming the changes are made, it will probably happen at a major OS update.

It would probably be best if it were enabled as an optional warning for some time (in the case of the system headers). Of course, they could still employ it with backwards compatibility for older compilers for new APIs.

Also, this change could be retrofitted quite easily (not that earlier compilers would make sense of the semantic difference between `id` and `instancetype`) by a simple typedef. One problem with a typedef is that it is a global declaration -- a compiler could restrict a word/modifier/attribute to a given scope, without causing all the pain of simulating a keyword by adding a global typedef. Apple's GCC may never support `instancetype`, so the logical way to introduce it for Apple's GCC may be a global `typedef` of `id`, which could cause problems for some people (with no semantic benefit, if that route were taken). Note that similar breaking changes have been made by Apple in the past.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, you're not just allowed to use the wrong array type, you're allowed to use the wrong type of *any object* with a convenience initializer that returns `id`.  For example, this compiles without a warning in sight:

```
NSMutableArray *a4 = [NSDictionary dictionary];
```

This is a side effect of using `id` to opt out of type safety, and as you note, it should be deprecated behavior and replaced with instancetype (which does throw an incompatible type warning when used in the manner above).

Unfortunately, it's not a bug.  `instancetype` being a fairly new keyword, it's adoption is not widespread yet, and it would be a bold move to start using it throughout Apple's frameworks.  You never know, there's always hope for the next SDK!

Comment: Thanks. I keep wondering why those methods should return `id` in the first place instead of the real type they're returning. Why throw away type safety like that?

Comment: So they don't break subclasses.  If you forgo type safety in an initializer, then the subclass S can override T's init method and return itself without a type check warning.  If ObjC were like java where initializers are unique and aren't inherited by default, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Hmm, I’ve found that **not** returning `id` is actually *not* a problem, as clang allows you to return a covariant subtype in an overridden method. So subclasses should be fine, too.