# Incompatible pointer types initializing 'SubClass *__strong' with an expression of type'BaseClass *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, compiler-construction, clang

In objective-C, why we can not `alloc`+`init` or `new` a base-class object with super-class, whilst we can use constructor of super-class to initialize?

Below is some code :

`s1` can be created quite comfortably.

```
NSMutableString *s1=[NSString string];
NSLog(@"%@",s1);
```

But `s2` and `s3` can not be, and gives a warning

`Incompatible pointer types initializing 'SubClass *__strong' with an expression of type'BaseClass *'`

```
NSMutableString *s2=[[NSString alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@",s2);

NSMutableString *s3=[NSString new];
NSLog(@"%@",s3);

//here no warning.
id mem=[NSString alloc];
NSMutableString *s4=[mem init];
NSLog(@"%@",s4);
```

What happens when we break alloc + init to two different statement?

Comment: Don't you think both questions are the same?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore : Yes i know, that is why I linked that one, I want ed to make it generalize for all sub-class and super class.

Comment: That's good but I'm hardly finding any difference between these two questions..

Comment: `s1` shouldn't be able to be created that way, the compiler should at least give a type warning... In fact they should all give warnings...

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Objective C, why am I allowed to assign an NSArray to an NSMutableArray without error or warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248437/in-objective-c-why-am-i-allowed-to-assign-an-nsarray-to-an-nsmutablearray-witho)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer can be found in [Objective-C Features](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-features) of the Clang 3.3 documentation:

> **Related result types**
>
> According to Cocoa conventions, Objective-C methods with certain names
>   (“init”, “alloc”, etc.) always return objects that are an instance of
>   the receiving class’s type. Such methods are said to have a “related
>   result type”, meaning that a message send to one of these methods will
>   have the same static type as an instance of the receiver class.

Therefore in

```
NSMutableString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

the type of the right hand side is actually `NSString *` and not `id`, and assigning that to an `NSMutableString *` gives a "Incompatible pointer types" warning.

On the other hand, the `string` method in

```
NSMutableString *s1 = [NSString string];
```

does not have a "related result type", so it just returns an `id` which can be assigned to the `NSMutableString *`.

Breaking alloc/init into separate statements suppresses the warning only if you use `id` as intermediate type. With `NSString` or `NSMutableString` you still get the warnings:

```
NSString *tmp4 = [NSString alloc];
NSMutableString *s4 = [tmp4 init]; // <-- Warning here

NSMutableString *tmp5 = [NSString alloc]; // <-- Warning here
NSMutableString *s5 = [tmp5 init];
```

---

According to the documentation, a method has a "related result type" if its return type is compatible with the type of its class and if:

- the first word is “alloc” or “new”, and the method is a class method, or
- the first word is “autorelease”, “init”, “retain”, or “self”, and the method is an instance method.

Comment: I should have checked the linked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248437/in-objective-c-why-am-i-allowed-to-assign-an-nsarray-to-an-nsmutablearray-witho first!! - But I wrote this answer independently without seeing the answers to the other question.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: You are welcome, it was an interesting topic. I learned something new doing the research.

Comment: But i got -1 in question :( But i added somthing new to it :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: You should not worry about a single downvote - it isn't worth it!

Answer (score 0):

**First case**

```
   NSMutableString *s2=[[NSString alloc] init];
   NSLog(@"%@",s2);
```

Here you are creating an `NSString` instance and send `init` message on it and finally you are assigning an `NSString` instance to `NSMutableString`. Here compiler knows that you are assigning an **incompatible pointer types**. So its warns you.

**Second case**

```
id mem=[NSString alloc];
NSMutableString *s3=[mem init];
```

You are creating an `NSString` instance and assigned as type `id`. and send `init` on an object of type `id`. **id** type is generic, compiler doesn't know its actual type till run time(dynamic typing). So it **wont warn you**. So problem is not in nested call.

Finally its my observation only :).

Comment: alloc also returns id, so is with s2.

Comment: alloc returns a new instance of the receiving class it can be anything that why return type is id.